# My sub domain is not working with Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a domain (ex: example.com) which is configured and working fine with AWS Route 53 as below configuration

[image]

I have A record point to a AWS ELB for 2 EC2 instances (such as A and B which have tomcat 7 installed and configured).

Now I want to setup a subdomain like java.example.com which is pointing to another EC instance such as C but so far is not luck

***What I have tried so far is***

Try 1. Create another hosted zone such as java.example.com and then create A record which point to the IP of C ==> not working

Try 2. Create A record under hosted zone example.com with name as java.example.com and value is IP of C => not working

Please advice what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a CNAME record named java.example.com and point that to the EC2 instance.

If you want to use A record then create a Load Balancer, put your EC2 behind the load balancer and then use the DNSName of the load balancer as the value for your A record

Check here for more details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Extract from above page is as follows

> **When Route 53 receives a DNS query for an alias record, Route 53 responds with the applicable value for that resource:**
>
> - An Amazon API Gateway custom regional API or edge-optimized API –
>     Route 53 responds with one or more IP addresses for your API.
> - An Amazon VPC interface endpoint – Route 53 responds with one or more IP addresses for your interface endpoint.
> - A CloudFront distribution – Route 53 responds with one or more IP addresses for CloudFront edge servers that can serve your content.
> - An Elastic Beanstalk environment – Route 53 responds with one or more IP addresses for the environment.
> - An ELB load balancer – Route 53 responds with one or more IP addresses for the load balancer.
> - An Amazon S3 bucket that is configured as a static website – Route 53 responds with one IP address for the Amazon S3 bucket.
> - Another Route 53 record in the same hosted zone – Route 53 responds as if the query is for the record that is referenced by the alias record.

Comment: Are you saying in hosted zone example.com, we create CNAME record with name is java.example.com and the value is IP of the instance C? Actually I tried it but it doesn't work. I got DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: On searching for "What is Dns_probe_finished_nxdomain?" I get the following..
This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network. Error code: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN... Are you sure that the EC2 is available and can be reached

Comment: Check this https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-dns_probe_finished_nxdomain-on-google-chrome/

Comment: Yes @Arafat. If I access the ip directly like http://xx.xx.xx.xxx , it is showing the page fine